# highcharts change rendered image source on click

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have created a chart based on Highcharts plugin, in which I have rendered an image (a button: "zoom.png").

This image has an `onCLick` event which resets my `yAxis` values.

I need to change the source of this image when the button is clicked; then change it back after the second click.

I managed to change the source of the image for the first click (it changes to "zoom1.png"); but when I click the button again it doesn't revert to the original source ("zoom.png")

Here is an example: **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/inadcod/FsLar/)**.

[Edit]: [Updated JSFiddle With Cool URIs for the Images](http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/FsLar/10/)

Comment: Thanks for editing the question. In my hurry to write it down, I forgot to hit some enters :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition you are checking for

```
if ($('image').attr('href', 'http://inadcod.com/img/zoom.png')) {
```

is invalid, as it is preceeded by

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

This creates the image again (in the newly created chart's load handler) with the original `zoom.png` hence the condition is always true, except the very 1st time, when there is no image.

You need to have a different check like a boolean variable out side to this chart which you will check and then flip every time it is clicked

[@jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/z7eyv/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is very complex and very well written.

Answer (score 1):

I cheated a bit by adding a class that denoted the zoom to the container node.  I'm not sure why it doesn't recognize the update to the href property, but this is one alternative:

http://jsfiddle.net/FsLar/4/